# Recursion PHP - after one permutation why doesn't this recursive function return a value?

Tags: php, recursion

```
function noOfPermutations($n, $permutation){
    $array = str_split($n);
    if(count($array)==1) {
        echo $permutation."\n";
        return $permutation;
    }else{
        $permutation++;
        noOfPermutations(array_sum($array), $permutation);
    }
}

echo "--".noOfPermutations(91,0)."--\n";
```

I'm trying to find the number of permutations for the sum of the digits in $n becomes single.
e.g. 91 -> 9+1 = 10 -> 1+0 = 1. This took 2 rounds so would return 2.
The function works fine if $n starts as a single digit number (it correctly returns 0) however more than one permutation and it just returns null. The first echo in the function outputs the correct value but the echo outside the function returns null.

Comment: I am getting the correct results for this. Idk why

Comment: Unless you need to use recursion, this sort of problem could be easily solved using a `while()` loop.

Comment: I am also getting correct result with your code

Comment: Weird, I'm using an online sandbox so maybe there's something different with that compared to an actual server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not doing anything with the returned value, I slightly re-elaborated your function in this way

```
function noOfPermutations($n, $permutation) {
    $array = str_split($n);
    if(count($array)==1) {
        echo "==>" . $permutation."\n";
    }else{
        $permutation++;
        $permutation = noOfPermutations(array_sum($array), $permutation);
    }
    return $permutation;
}

echo "--".noOfPermutations(91,0)."--\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in your title *after one permutation why doesn't this recursive function `return` a value?*:

```
return noOfPermutations(array_sum($array), $permutation);
```

You might also look at [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing nothing with the result. You go one deeper in the else, but do nothing with the outcome of that.
I'm guessing it should be something along the lines of:

```
function noOfPermutations(int $n, int $permutation = 0){
    $array = str_split($n);
    if( count($array) > 1 ) {
        $permutation += noOfPermutations(array_sum($array),  $permutation);
        //  ^^--- Now we actually do something with the result 
    }

    return $permutation; 
}
```

<sup>I've added a little codeformat and typehint as well</sup>

---

Alternatively, you can make the `$permutation` by reference, that way you dont have to return it.  I dont recommend it, but it might be a solution for someone sometime.